# How to reformat Panda to_period('W-MON') and have correct date?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am converting my date in W-MON datetime format as follow:

`df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.to_period('W-MON')`

The result I get are giving me week starting Tuesday and finishing Monday: 
`2020-05-12/2020-05-18`

From the doc it seems that 'W-MON' will lead to a week starting on Monday.

Also is it possible to reformat it to only have the daterange as the week starting: 
`2020-05-12`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the additional keywords `closed="left"` and `label="left"` so it knows to group starting on Monday instead of ending on Monday

Answer (score 0):

The solution to have week starting on Monday is to precise: 
"W-SUN" as the day precise is the day ending of the week.